# MATLAB decic function can not find consistent initial conditions - DAE (differential algebraic) system solved in Maple

Tags: matlab

Dear stackoverflow users with MATLAB knowledge,

I am trying to solve a differential algebraic system of 12 variables using 12 equations. I have already solved the system in Maple, but would like to code the entire program (which will be based off the solving method of the system) in MATLAB for various reasons (GUI coding etc.)

However, I can not succeed at getting MATLAB to solve the system. I refuse to believe MATLAB can't do it, but at the same time I am not sure what I could do differently to succeed at solving the system. I've tried to implement the rough solving methods for the ode15i, ode15s and ode23t solvers up until the step of finding consistent initial conditions ([according to the official mathworks method](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/set-up-your-dae-problem.html) ). All of the methods fail at this step. Either it's due to a 'Convergence failure in DECIC.' or 'Cannot resolve the constraints. Try using more accurate approximations of consistent initial conditions'. I have also had to simplify to problem because otherwise one of the solving method gets stuck at the step of verifying the differential index (it throws the error 'Exponent overflow.')

I will put the script with my code and some comments below. I use two classes in the script and will put the code for them down below that. They are both part of a constants package I am putting together for my program.

SCRIPT

```
clear;

import constants.AtomicWeights
import constants.Universal

% Initialisation variables & parameters
t = sym('t');

Al_i = sym('Al_i(t)');
Si_i = sym('Si_i(t)');
AlO_i = sym('AlO_i(t)');
SiO_i = sym('SiO_i(t)');
Al_b = sym('Al_b(t)');
Si_b = sym('Si_b(t)');
AlO_b = sym('AlO_b(t)');
SiO_b = sym('SiO_b(t)');

R_Al = sym('R_Al(t)');
R_Si = sym('R_Si(t)');
R_AlO = sym('R_AlO(t)');
R_SiO = sym('R_SiO(t)');

Al_b0 = 0.3;
AlO_b0 = 50;
Si_b0 = 0;
SiO_b0 = 5;

A = 0.025^2*pi;
T = 1600;
Rho_m = 7000*10^3;
Rho_s = 2850*10^3;
W_m = 500;
W_s = 75;

m_Al = 3*10^(-4);
m_Si = m_Al;
m_AlO = 3*10^(-5);
m_SiO = m_AlO;

MW_AlO = 2*AtomicWeights.Al + 3*AtomicWeights.O;
MW_SiO = AtomicWeights.Si + 2*AtomicWeights.O;
MW_CaO = AtomicWeights.Ca + AtomicWeights.O;

e_AlonSi = 0.058;
e_AlonAl = 0.045;
e_SionSi = 0.11;
e_SionAl = 0.0056;

% Rate equations
R_eq_Al1 = R_Al == m_Al*Rho_m*(Al_b-Al_i)/AtomicWeights.Al;
R_eq_Al2 = R_Al == -W_m*diff(Al_b,t)/(AtomicWeights.Al*A);
R_eq_Si1 = R_Si == m_Si*Rho_m*(Si_b-Si_i)/AtomicWeights.Si;
R_eq_Si2 = R_Si == -W_m*diff(Si_b,t)/(AtomicWeights.Si*A);
R_eq_AlO1 = R_AlO == m_AlO*Rho_s*(AlO_b-AlO_i)/MW_AlO;
R_eq_AlO2 = R_AlO == -W_s*diff(AlO_b,t)/(MW_AlO*A);
R_eq_SiO1 = R_SiO == m_SiO*Rho_s*(SiO_b-SiO_i)/MW_SiO;
R_eq_SiO2 = R_SiO == -W_s*diff(SiO_b,t)/(MW_SiO*A);

% Mass balance equations
M_eq1 = R_Al/4 == R_SiO/3;
M_eq2 = R_Al/4 == -R_AlO/2;
M_eq3 = R_Al/4 == -R_Si/3;

% Equilibrium equation
G0 = -720680 + 133*T;
SiO_i_x =(SiO_i/(100*MW_SiO))/(AlO_i/(100*MW_AlO) + SiO_i/(100*MW_SiO) ...
    + (100-SiO_i-AlO_i)/(100*MW_CaO));
g_Al_Hry = 1;
g_Si_Hry = 1;
g_SiO_Ra = 0.01; % Originally this value was the following: 
% 10^((-2.2262739343996234 + 2.5308576141282924)/(0.056138749134701696 - ...
% 0.05016456400557766)*(SiO_i/100 - 0.056138749134701696) - ...
% 2.2262739343996234);
% I had to replace it with a simple constant value to avoid that
% isLowIndexDAE(eqs, vars) in 'solving method 1' would throw the error
% 'Exponent overflow.'

ln_h_Al = log(g_Al_Hry)+log(10)*e_SionAl*Si_i/100+log(Al_i/100);
ln_h_Si = log(g_Si_Hry)+log(10)*e_AlonSi*Al_i/100+log(Si_i/100);
ln_a_Al2O3 = log(0.30);
ln_a_SiO2 = log(g_SiO_Ra*SiO_i_x);
K_cst = -G0/(Universal.R*T);
E_eq = K_cst == 3*ln_h_Si+2*ln_a_Al2O3-4*ln_h_Al-3*ln_a_SiO2;

% Gather equations & variables
eqs = [R_eq_Al1, R_eq_Al2, R_eq_Si1, R_eq_Si2, R_eq_AlO1, R_eq_AlO2, ...
    R_eq_SiO1, R_eq_SiO2, M_eq1, M_eq2, M_eq3, E_eq];
vars = [Al_i, Al_b, Si_i, Si_b, AlO_i, AlO_b, SiO_i, SiO_b, R_Al, ...
    R_Si, R_SiO, R_AlO];

alg_eqs = [R_eq_Al1, R_eq_Si1, R_eq_AlO1, R_eq_SiO1, ...
    M_eq1, M_eq2, M_eq3, E_eq];
alg_vars = [Al_i, Si_i, AlO_i, SiO_i, R_Al, ...
    R_Si, R_SiO, R_AlO];

% --- Solving method 1 for solver ode15i ---

% [eqs, vars, R] = reduceDifferentialOrder(eqs, vars);
% if isLowIndexDAE(eqs, vars)
%    [DAEs,DAEvars] = reduceRedundancies(eqs, vars);
% else
%    [DAEs, DAEvars, R, oldIndex] = reduceDAEIndex(eqs, vars);
%    [DAEs,DAEvars] = reduceRedundancies(DAEs, DAEvars);
%    if isnan(oldIndex)
%        [ODEs, constraints] = reduceDAEToODE(eqs, vars);
%     end
% end
% 
% bool = isLowIndexDAE(DAEs, DAEvars);
% F = daeFunction(DAEs, DAEvars);
% y0est = [1; Al_b0; 1; Si_b0; 1; AlO_b0; 1; SiO_b0; 1];
% yp0est = zeros(9,1);
% opt = odeset('RelTol', 10.0^(-7), 'AbsTol' , 10.0^(-7));
% [y0, yp0] = decic(F, 0, y0est, [], yp0est, []);

% --- Solving method 2 for solver ode15i ---

% [ODEs, constraints] = reduceDAEToODE(eqs, vars);
% f = daeFunction(ODEs, vars);
% y0est = [1; Al_b0; 1; Si_b0; 1; AlO_b0; 1; SiO_b0; 1; 1; 1; 1];
% yp0est = zeros(12,1);
% opt = odeset('RelTol', 10.0^(-7), 'AbsTol' , 10.0^(-7));
% [y0, yp0] = decic(ODEs, vars, constraints, 0, y0est, [], ...
%    yp0est, opt);

% --- Solving method 3 for solver ode15s and ode23t ---

% [DAEs,DAEvars] = reduceRedundancies(eqs, vars);
% [M,F] = massMatrixForm(eqs,vars);
% M = odeFunction(M, vars);
% F = odeFunction(F, vars);
% 
% y0est = [0.0001; Al_b0; 0.0001; Si_b0; 0.0001; AlO_b0; 0.0001; SiO_b0; ...
%     0.0001];
% yp0est = zeros(9,1);
% opt = odeset('Mass', M, 'InitialSlope', yp0est,...
%     'RelTol', 10.0^(-7), 'AbsTol' , 10.0^(-7));
% [y0, yp0] = decic(@(t,y,yp) M(t,y)*yp - F(t,y), 0, y0est, [], yp0est, [], opt);

% --- Solving method 4 (trying find consistent initial conditions 
% manually) has not been fruitful either until now ---

% [alg_eqs, alg_vars] = reduceRedundancies(alg_eqs, alg_vars);
% alg_eqs = subs(alg_eqs, [Al_b, Si_b, AlO_b, SiO_b], ...
%     [Al_b0, Si_b0, AlO_b0, SiO_b0]);
% S = solve(alg_eqs,0);
```

ATOMIC WEIGHTS CLASS

```
classdef AtomicWeights
   % ATOMICWEIGHTS list of atomic weights in g/mol
     properties (Constant)
        Al = 26.9815385;
        Si = 28.085;
        Fe = 55.845;
        O = 15.999;
        Ca = 40.078;
        Mg = 24.305;
        Ti = 47.867;
     end
end
```

UNIVERSAL

```
classdef Universal
   % UNIVERSAL list of universal constants
   %
   % R = gas constant expressed in m^3*Pa/(K*mol)
     properties (Constant)
        R = 8.3144621;
     end
  end
```